# Unable to create GPU enabled VM in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, virtual-machine

I have a $300 free trial credits for GCP. I am trying to re-train YoloV8 model on my image dataset. Unfortunately, I am unable to create VM instance with GPU. I have tried to create it in several different regions, but so far not successful. Is it due to the fact that I am on free trial? Is there anyone who had similar issues and managed to solve it finally?

Thanks in advance!

I tried to increase the quotas, but I think I was lost in documentation on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately GPU is not included for the free tier offered by GCP. [1] The best people to help you if you need GPU resources would be the sales team [2]. Regarding quota increase, you need to use your current resources to improve your usage history as this is the basis for quota increase.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/free-cloud-features#free-trial

[2]
https://cloud.google.com/contact

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replying. I will contact them!